# How to understand logic in tree node class method?

Tags: python-3.x, logical-operators

Here is the class:

```
class TreeNode:

    def __init__(self, key, left=None, right=None, parent=None):
        self.key = key
        self.left_child = left
        self.right_child = right
        self.parent = parent

    def is_left_child(self):
        return self.parent and self.parent.left_child == self
```

For the method "is_left_child(self)", why do we need to check the boolean values of both "self.parent" and "self.parent.left_child == self? Wouldn't

```
self.parent.left_child == self
```

check the boolean value of self.parent anyway? Is it simply an alternative to writing:

```
if self.parent.left_child == self
    return True
```

? Thereby avoiding having to write an explicit "if" statement and still return a boolean value?

Comment: Suppose `self` didn't have a parent; what would `self.parent.left_child` evaluate to?

Comment: It would return an attribute error if it is a string and not be evaluated. However, it would be evaluated if it is a node.

Comment: Assuming you want to avoid that error, that's why the test is there.

Comment: if `self.parent is None` then without the guard you get an exception. You could of course use a `try` to deal with that but it is cleaner here (IMHO) to test if `self.parent` is thruthy which `None` is not.

Comment: Let's say I create a node: a = TreeNode("a"). Then I create another node: b = TreeNode("b", parent = a). Then set a.left_child = b. Then return self.parent and self.parent.left_child == self is some what redundant. Take out the self.parent from the class and it works fine. I think I will make this the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say I create a node:

```
a = TreeNode("a")
```

Then I create another node:

```
b = TreeNode("b", parent = a)
```

Then set:

```
a.left_child = b
```

Then:

```
def is_left_child(self):
    return self.parent and self.parent.left_child == self
```

is some what redundant. Take out the self.parent from the class's is_left_child method definition:

```
def is_left_child(self):
    return self.parent and self.parent.left_child == self
```

and it works fine. Full code:

```
class TreeNode:

def __init__(self, key, left=None, right=None, parent=None):
    self.key = key
    self.left_child = left
    self.right_child = right
    self.parent = parent

def is_left_child(self):
    return self.parent.left_child == self
```

Try it yourself:

```
a = TreeNode("a", 3)
b = TreeNode("b", 5, parent=a)
a.left_child = b
b.is_left_child()

   True
```